# Are `a.argmin(axis=0)` and `np.argmin(a, axis=0)` the same?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, are `a.argmin(axis=0)` and `np.argmin(a, axis=0)` the same?

http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#argmin seems to suggest that they aren't.

Comment: How is this "iteration with broadcasting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is a NumPy array, they're the same. The `argmin` function also supports array-like objects, whereas the method only exists on actual arrays. This is true for most cases where a NumPy function and method have the same name, aside from a few differences like the `sort` method operating in-place when the `sort` function makes a copy.

Comment: +1. The code is very readable and 'says' exactly the same thing, [link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L935)